# Distribution of distinguishable items to indistinguishable cells

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Most books talks about this:

> Number of distributions of $n$ **distinguishable** objects to $r$ **distinguishable** cells, when repetitions allowed, such that each cell receives
>
> - 1 item is $n^r$
> - 0 or 1 item is $(n+1)^r$

But they do not talk about what happens when distributions is done from $n$ **distinguishable** objects to $r$ **indistinguishable** cells. I guess I have to divide the above results by $r!$, giving me $\frac{n^r}{r!}$ and $\frac{(n+1)^r}{r!}$ respectively. **Q1.** Is it so?

Does them same applies when

- **Q2.** each cell receives 0 or more and 1 or more objects?
- **Q3.** repetitions are not allowed?

Comment: $\frac{n^r}{r!}$ cannot be the result. For, say, $n=k=3$, $\frac{n^r}{r!}=\frac{3^3}{3!}=\frac92$ not even an integer.

Comment: Yes I realized that. I tried out manually enumerating outcomes of some examples. Say $n=6, r=5$, When the number contain 2 numbers say 1 & 2. Then we will have {11112,11122,11222,12222}. Deleting first and last digit in each, we get {111,112,122,222}. For $r=6$, it will be {1111,1112,1122,1222,2222} and so on for larger $r$. For $r=5$ and when the number contains 3 numbers say 1,2,3, then we will have {12311,12312,12313,12322,12323,12333}. Removing first 3 digits in each, we will get {11,12,13,22,23,33}. I guess this requires inclusion exclusion.

Comment: Just trying to find pattern above in example in above comment, so that I can generalize to come up with some series. I dont think any closed formula is possible. But finding well defined series is also getting difficult. I hope I am making at least some sense in above comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The answer is ${r+n-1} \choose {n-1}$. If your cells are indistinguishable, then a distribution is uniquely determined by knowing how often each of the $n$ distinguishable objects is occurring in the cells. If object $i$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) occurs $h_i$ times, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n h_i = r$, and obviously $h_i \in \mathbb N, h_i \ge 0$.

Since our objects are distinguishable, the order in the sum matters. Conversely, if we have such a sum it can be used to define a distribution as described above.

What we are looking for is called a weak composition of a number ($r$) into a fixed number of summands ($n$). At https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) you can find the formula I gave above.

**Addition**: Since the result for Q1 is a well known formula for choosing (without considering order, but allowing repetition) $r$ objects from a pool of $n$ different ones, it seems interesting to find a direct mapping between the two problems, without the 'detour' of weak compositions of a number. This can be done as follows:

Each cell contains exactly one object. We don't care about the order of the cells (they are indistinguishable), and the objects can repeat. This means we have to choose $r$ times (once for each cell) one of the $n$ different objects, allowing objects to repeat.

Yet another way is using the popular "stars and bars" model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29):

Since the cells are indistinguishable, you can order them any way you want. If we assume that the objects are represented by numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$, we can order each distribution by putting all cells with a $1$ first, then all cells with a $2$, a.s.o. In the stars and bars model, the stars are the $r$ cells. If we have ordered the cells as explained above, we can uniquely determine the distribution by putting the bars at the positions between the stars where the objects change.

The first bar comes at the uniquely defined position where all stars before it contain a $1$ or lower number and and all stars after it contain a $2$ or higher number. This would be "after the last $1$", if there are cells with a $1$, or immediately before the first star, if there is no cell with a $1$. The second bar 
comes at the uniquely defined position where all stars before it contain a $2$ or lower number and and all stars after it contain a $3$ or higher number. This is continued until the $(n-1)$-th bar.

The $n-1$ bars can freely occupy all the $r+1$ possible bar positions, each selection (which is with repetition, as bars can occupy the same position) corresponds to one distribution of objects onto cells. So the number of possible distributions is

$$ {(n-1) + (r+1) - 1 \choose (r+1)-1}  = {n+r-1 \choose r} = {r+n-1 \choose n-1},$$

as before.

**Answer for Q2**: The meaning was clarified in the comments below:

"In 2nd question, I meant repetitions allowed across cells, not within single cell."

This is then basically Q1, your new $n_{Q2}$ (number of objects) just became much bigger. If you allow any subset of your set of objects to be placed into a cell (including the empty set), you have in essence just created a new set of objects that consists of all the subsets of your original object set. This means $n_{Q2} = 2^n$ in that case. If you disallow the empty set, you have $n_{Q2} = 2^n - 1$. You need to plug this into the formula above, with $r$ unchanged.

Comment: So what is the result when $n=r=2$ and $n=r=3$?

Comment: Is there a deeper meaning to the question than just plugging the values into the formula?

Comment: There is no dipper : ) meaning. However, in case of $n=r=2$ we have only two possibilities to arrange $2$ distinguishable balls in two indistinguishable boxes: both of them are in one box and they are in different boxes. Your formula ${r+n-1} \choose {n-1}$ says ${3} \choose {1}$.

Comment: @zoli , no, Ingix is correct. for $n=r=2$ say $\{1,2\}$, there are three possible distributions: ${11,22,12}$

Comment: @Zoli: Then we are talking about a different problem. In Q1 each cell contains exactly one object, see anir above for the example. That would be the (to me) straigthforward change from distinguishable cells initially described in the problem. If we allow your interpretation of multiple objects in one cell, the the original answer of $n^r$ would be incorrect.

Comment: @Ingix quite surprised. This seems correct for Q1. Surprised because this is same as that for star and bar problems which are distribution of **indistinguishable items** to **distinguishable cells** with **no repetitions** and each cell getting **zero or more** items. Right? Now guessing how (distinguishable items + indistinguishable cells + repetition + exactly 1 item/cell) turns conceptually same as (indistinguishable items + distinguishable cells + no repetition + 0 or more items/cell)!!!??? Any comments?

Comment: @anir: I was suprised myself. Initially it looked like it would be some partition number when I wrote down the sum formulation. Then I thought it would be even more complicated because in this case the order mattered. But when I looked it up, it has the "simple" solution I found in wikipedia. If I can can come up with a good direct isomorphism between the problems I'll add that to my solution.

Comment: That would be awesome. There has to be some conceptual reasoning for Q1 getting reduced to star and bar problem. It must be somewhat simpler. Will give it a try. Also there are some other questions in original question. I will be giving some more thoughts to them and will comment here if I come with something. Please comment hints if you have any for other questions.

Comment: Q2 and is unclear to me. Q2: What limits do you have in place that prevent a million copies of object 1 being placed in a cell? If there are no limits, this means you have infinite possibilities. Q3: Obviously, we need $n\ge r$, then the question is simply how many ways we can select $r$ different objects from the pool of $n$. I think you know the answer.

Comment: In 2nd question, I meant repetitions allowed across cells, not within single cell. This was implicit in 1st question due to 1 object/cell. For eg, for **distinguishable** objects & **distinguishable** cells, with repetition allowed across cells, but not inside cell, when cell can have zero or more items, first cell will have $2^{n+1}$ possibilities of content. Same for all cells. This gives $2^{(n+1)r}$ total possibilities. For 1 or more onjects/cell, it will be $2^{nr}$ What will happen with **distinguishable** objects+**indistinguishable** cells?

Comment: For 3rd question, I meant repetitions not allowed for all above combinations of possibilities: (1+ items/cell or 0+ items/cell or exactly 1 item/cell) for distinguishable items and indistinguishable cells. I got them all. For 1+ items/cell or 0+ items/cell, the solution involves Stirling numbers. Surprisingly again,as you pointed out, for exact 1 item per cell,  it becomes combination $\binom{n}{r}$. Now guessing, what will be outcome for all these combination of possibilities with zero or one item/cell...

Comment: I guess I am understanding you. Just to confirm, for Q2, did you mean $\binom{2^n+r-1}{r}$ for 0 or more items/cell and $\binom{2^n+r-2}{r}$ for 1 or more items/cell? If yes, then, omg, how did you come up with this?